# Azure ACI on Windows - How to access shared folder in container from on-premises and access Azure fileshare

Tags: azure-container-instances, azure-files

i know that we can access azure file share from only the Linux Azure Container Instance. (not windows)
link here

1. So how can i access Azure file share from an Azure ACI of windows ?
2. Can i access a shared folder on Azure ACI container from on-premises windows machine ?Azure ACI has public IP address. So can we access like \IP Address\shareName   ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Q1. So how can I access Azure file share from an Azure ACI of windows ?**

As you know, mounting an Azure Files share is currently restricted to Linux containers. So you cannot use this way to access the file share from the windows instance. I suggest you use the [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) to access the file share, in this way, you need to configure it yourself.

**Q2. Can I access a shared folder on Azure ACI container from on-premises windows machine ?Azure ACI has public IP address. So can we access like \IP Address\shareName ?**

For this question, you can configure the container instance as an NFS server, then you can access the NFS server in the way you knew before.

Comment: How to configure container instance as an NFS Server ?

Comment: @MSTechnie Like you configure the NFS in local machine. Do you know how to configure the NFS server?

Comment: @MSTechnie Any updates? Does it solve your problem? If it solves your problem please accept it.

Comment: @MSTechnie What is the reason you don't accept when it helps you?! It's not difficult to accept.

Comment: i thought there was a way to access a folder in a container using the \\IP Address\foldername\ . i dont know how to configure NFS for container. Can you please give a simple example or url

Comment: @MSTechnie Take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-how-to-create-nfs-shares?tabs=azure-portal). It must help.